# Advanced custom fields Repeater conditional statement not working

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, conditional-tags

Even if no value for a field is entered my elements inside my echo still show inside my conditional statement.

Thinking that is just checking if the field exists rather then checking if a value is entered.

```
<?php if( have_rows('catalog', 'options') ): ?>

<?php while( have_rows('catalog', 'options') ): the_row(); 

if(get_sub_field('catalog_product_title'));

{
    $catalog_product_title = get_sub_field('catalog_product_title');
    echo '<tr><th colspan="3" align="left"><h1>' . $catalog_product_title . '</h1></th></tr>';
}

?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(get_sub_field('catalog_product_title'));
```

> **;** is for ending a statement in php

If you remove that ; your if statement should work.

Comment: Thanks just started really digging into PHP, spent hours before asking here. Feeling kinda dumb

Comment: Thats alright. We all start somewhere.